# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT'

Tags: python, opencv

I work in Windows 10 and use python 3.6 and install with pip a opencv-python

after then install opencv_python‑3.3.1+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
Opencv test cod is:

```
from time import time
from numpy import uint8
from numpy.random import rand
import cv2

xy=(512,512)
Nf = 500

def fpsopencv(dat):
    tic = time()
    for i in dat:
        cv2.imshow('test',i)
        cv2.waitKey(1) #integer milliseconds, 0 makes wait forever
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return Nf / (time()-tic)


imgs = (rand(Nf,xy[0],xy[1])*255).astype(uint8)
fps = fpsopencv(imgs)

print(fps,'fps')
```

It's work well.

But if a want to use a SIFT in my code:

```
sift = cv2.SIFT()
```

I always get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT'
```

I don't know what is a solution. Somebody can help me? (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: it seems that it was removed from the default installation. Look at [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/). You can still have it but you need to change the way to call it. At least this is valid for 3.0, I think for 3.3 as well, I haven't tested it in the current one.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html